# EC2 AWS getting error when i try to open http://ec2-15-185-40-86.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This site can’t be reached
ec2-15-185-40-86.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My aws ec2 site is stopped automatically. Please help me out how to make it working.

Comment: After removing the port number 8000 in the url, like this:ec2-15-185-40-86.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com I'm able to access your site:)

Comment: Yes i can access backend portion but not front end instance.

Comment: If you want to use a specific port, you need to specify it in security groups attached to the instance

Comment: actually url was working in 8000 port from ec2 but now it not working some how. I dont have access of aws server. so i dont get how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please tell me specifically how to and where to add this port. Thanks for helping.